# NodeJS 4 Express static resources not found

Tags: node.js, express, resources

I have the static resource definitions in my Express project

```
app.use('/components', express.static( __dirname + '/components/'));
app.use('/components/persist/lib/', express.static( __dirname + '/components/persist/lib/'));
```

Here is include on page

```
<script src="components/persist/lib/persist-min.js"></script>
<script src="components/client.js"></script>
```

First definition works fine, but second does not. That error

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

What is wrong in this configuration?

Comment: now try this. but this order does not works as that variant
app.use('/components/persist/lib/', express.static( __dirname + '/components/persist/lib/'));
app.use('/components', express.static( __dirname + '/components/'));